# I want to create a view in mongodb for only 2019 data and connect it to Power BI

Tags: mongodb

I'm creating a new view with this following code:

```
db.createView("only_2019_data","order",{created_at:{$gte:new ISODate('2019-01-10')}})
```

However after it's created I'm trying to query the new collection and I cant see any data:

```
db.only_2019_data.find().pretty()
```

Returns an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

A view receives a `pipeline` as it's 3rd arguments, by definition a pipeline is:

> An array that consists of the aggregation pipeline stage(s).

Meaning you just have to tinker your `createView` call to this:

```
db.createView("only_2019_data","order",[{$match: {created_at:{$gte:new ISODate('2019-01-10')}}}])
```

Comment: The code ran and now i want to import this view into Power BI but there's no option showing in display option menu..only DB is been shown for loading data.!!?

Comment: I'm not sure how the Power BI sync works but a view in mongo does not create another collection, if that's your problem you should just run the pipeline with $out to create that collection, a view only creates an alias and runs that aggregation as a preprocess for every query you make (making it not so efficient).